# SPSiteDataQuery throwing exception while setting it's Query property

Tags: spsitedataquery

I am querying multiple task lists in a SharePoint site. I can retrieve the results until I set the Query property and specify the OrderBy clause. The detailed exception and code is pasted below. Appreciate any help

```
private void doTasks(SPWeb currentWeb, SPSiteDataQuery q)
    {

    q.Query =
         "<OrderBy>" +
         "   <FieldRef Name='Priority' />" +
         "   <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />" +
         "</OrderBy>";

    // Specify the view fields.
    q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' Type='Text'/>";
    q.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' Type='User' Nullable='TRUE' />";
    q.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='PercentComplete' Type='Number' Nullable='TRUE'/>";
    results = currentWeb.GetSiteData(q);

    if (results.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
             //blah!
    }
}
```

> [COMException (0x80020009):
>   0x80020009]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CrossListQuery(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +174
>
> [SPException]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   +27428978
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns) +27812419
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery query) +521
>   StoraEnso.Collaboration.WebParts.SubSiteItemAggregator.SubSiteItemAggregator.doTasks(SPWeb
>   currentWeb, SPSiteDataQuery q) +189
>   StoraEnso.Collaboration.WebParts.SubSiteItemAggregator.SubSiteItemAggregator.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +441
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, WebPart part) +43
>
> [WebPartException]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, WebPart part) +19826502
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, WebPart part) +64
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderZoneCell(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Boolean bMoreParts, WebPart part) +1997
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderWebParts(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, ArrayList webParts) +508
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +1000
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +253
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +87 
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +53
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +240    System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +38    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4240

Comment: Is that the whole exception and call stack? I dont see your code in the callstack?

Comment: I have updated with complete exception details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the migration some page layouts were using the SPSiteDataQuery to query the ContentTypes across different webs to get the content. The code worked fine in SP2007 but in SP2010 it was throwing exception as mentioned below:

**Solution**

Make sure the field your using for the order by is included in the SPSiteDataQuery.ViewFields property. As simple as that!